# How to randomly generate trees with n vertices in C++?

Tags: c++, graph

Given n: the number of vertices, I want to randomly generate a tree with n vertices.
Currently, I am using random_shuffle() to generate random sequences of n vertices to generate only linear trees. But how can I make it random enough to include other tree types as well in C++?

Comment: there's no such a thing as a "purely random" tree; do you mean, how to generate a pseudorandom tree following a *uniform* probability distribution over the set of trees with n vertices ?

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Yes.

Answer (score 2):

assuming your goal is to generate a pseudorandom tree following a **uniform** probability distribution over the set of rooted labeled trees with n vertices, the solution is to generate a so called **Prüfer code**, that is a uniformly generated random (n-2)-tuple of numbers in [1,n].

The wiki article has a ready to use pseudocode:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence

> But how can I make it random enough

there's no such a thing as 'random enough'; **you** need to specify what properties the tree distribution should have (and more than one such distribution could exist). In the special case of a finite set ( such as the set of all trees with n vertices ) you can always uniquely define a uniform distribution on it, but this is by no means neither 'more random', nor 'more natural', nor anything ... it's up to you ( and your ultimate goal ) to decide if that's the right distribution or not.

Comment: Which is also used by python's [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.tree.random_tree.html#networkx.generators.tree.random_tree) implementing ```generators.tree.random_tree``` (supporting it's practical importance somewhat).